# How can I convert a JPEG image to a RAW image with a Linux command?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, imagemagick

I have a series of JPEG images taken with [Canon Powershot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_PowerShot) to JPEG. How can I convert/transform them to RAW images?

Not with a graphical tool, but from the command line!

NB : Using raw images to stack them in Siril astrophoto application (https://siril.org/fr/)

Comment: Maybe you will receive answers more useful for you if you tell us why you want raw images ([edit] the question). Compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310).

Comment: Welcome out on SuperUser. Note that the jpg saving option is lossy. If you need to convert again into a specific RAW format, you need to know those specifications. Usually it is meaningless because the flaws are already iside the images and you cannot go back. But if you need, [edit] your post adding the model and maybe it will be possible to give you some hints or solutions.

Comment: Lolotux, you do not win a dime when doing this. Probably you heard about the advantages of the RAW format over JPEG. That is true. But you can only profit from it when your cameras saves them in RAW format (at the begining of the production chain). Having had a Canon Powershot (A75) myself I remember there was a setting where the camera would write RAW and middle quality jpeg instead of high quality jpeg. Converting afterwards is like recoding an old video in 720x576 to 4k. You won't get a single detail more out of it. Furthermore, there is more software that is processing JPEG than RAW.

Comment: RAW is not a format. Rather it is a label that means sensor data from a manufacturer. Different hardware generates different sensor data so there is no RAW format but rather there are multiple different sensor data formats that are called RAW because they are raw sensor data (by raw I mean unprocessed like food before being cooked and RAW also means raw only some people feel like they need to capitalize it)

Comment: @slebetma: But in this particular case it is likely a defined published format ([CDIFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_Image_File_Format)) - not literally in raw sensor output format, but in a lossless (well-defined) (binary) format.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the images to .raw files? Because some software needs the images in that format? Is the quality loss acceptable?

Comment: @PeterMortensen - There are three different Canon RAW formats. They abandoned CIFF in 2004, for TIFF-based CR2 & now QT-based CR3. https://exiftool.org/canon_raw.html "Converting to RAW" is still not a good idea & nothing absolutely **needs** RAW as input, whether the conversion is otherwise pointless or not. if you were to attempt any kind of 'rough guess' conversion, then the more open DNG format would be as good as any to aim for - https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/digital-negative.html

Comment: Anyhow, if a client is asking you for raw images and you give them raw images created from a .jpeg, I wouldn't expect to get work from that client again.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - too true… but if a client is asking for the RAWs, I'd be hesitant anyway. They pay you for your results, not your input format. It's like a supermarket asking for the cow, rather than the milk ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin, I have (err, my wife's sole-proprietership business has) a client who has their own colorists. They really do want to make sure the milk is processed to their own internal standards. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - that's fair. I only supply 'results'. I hadn't considered your being contracted to supply 'originals', only 'if you don't like my results, why are you using me?' ;)

Comment: Pre-COVID, they would have brought all the talent into their own studio and shot things on-site. Not possible today, but they still want the images to come out looking the same, no matter where they were collected.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - again, fair. I work mainly in the film/TV industry, where everybody gets covid-tested (almost) every day, before they're allowed on set. It's the (expensive) way they stay open. My nose feels like a much-recycled bottle these days, brush-cleaned more than I ever thought possible ;)

Comment: This is comparable to saying "I took a picture of an original oil painting and now I want to turn this picture back into the oil painting".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, ...that surprises me, since it's not my analogy; I just continued it, after Tetsujin first used it (in staking a position -- again, not _my_ position -- for which your responding comment strikes me as a valid counterargument).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It was a joke relating to two statements in the conversation you were having with Tetsujin. Apparently not a very good one.

Comment: (The link in your profile to your blog, `monblog.system-linux.net/blog`, does not work (***Not Found. The requested URL was not found on this server.***). The HTTP version - the HTTPS ***does not work at all*** ("Unable to connect").)

Answer (score 58):

#### Original RAW images cannot be restored.

Selecting JPEG instead of RAW saves space by sacrificing quality.
This operation is irreversible and lossy.
Simply speaking this means you can't go back.

Sadly you may only select RAW format instead of JPEG next time before you shot.

**Note:** You could technically find a way to turn the current jpg image into RAW format, but it will not be the same RAW image you might have if you shot and saved directly in RAW format.

---

Searching in the [Canon support](https://hk.canon/en/support/8202873200) you may read

> the camera can capture images in JPEG and RAW format.

> JPEG
> Images  Processed in the camera for optimal image quality and compressed to reduce file size. However, **the compression process is irreversible, and images cannot be restored to their original, unprocessed state.** Image processing may also cause some loss of image quality.

> RAW
> "Raw" (unprocessed) data, recorded with essentially no loss of image quality from the camera's image processing. The data cannot be used in this state for viewing on a computer or printing. You must first process images on the camera or use the software (Digital Photo Professional) to convert images to JPEG or TIFF files. Images can be adjusted with minimal loss of image quality.

Comment: Note that there is not currently a single standard "RAW format".

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Right and proper. RAW formats are service formats used by the manufacturer to quickly save the contents of the CCD into the buffer and in case on the storage device. They depend on choices dictated by the geometry of the CCD etc etc... Seldom only the manufacturer knows the functions used to convert the RAW picture into another format. Often the transformation is not reversible. See this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1620628/257269) below for some words more.

Comment: "Seldom only the manufacturer knows the functions used to convert the RAW picture into another format."  Very interesting... I just learned something new!  I think for the first word of that sentence, you meant "Usually" instead of "Seldom"... is that correct?

Comment: Maybe it is poorly worded. With "Seldom ... Often..." I just wanted to express my impression: sometimes the algorithm is not disclosed, more often there are (see `convert`) ways of converting a specific RAW format into (e.g.) JPEG, even more often the algorithms are not invertible (simple example: shrinking 12 or 14-bits into 8)...

Comment: I am always curious about downvoters ... Please comment and let me (we) know what you disagree, it might be useful to know.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket what about DNG?

Comment: @data I'm sorry, I don't quite understand your question.  Can you add some more detail?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket you said "there is not currently a single standard RAW format", which is not true - DNG is a standard raw format.

Comment: @data I see. I think your interpretation is likely due to the ambiguities of the English language.  Try reading what I wrote this way: "RAW format is not a single standard".  In other words, there are many RAW formats.

Comment: @Hastur: "Seldom" means "very rarely" i.e. using it implies that whatever you're talking about happens hardly at all. In this context you probably want something like "Occasionally" :)

Answer (score 30):

"Raw" is not a well defined format. Examining
[Wikipedia Raw image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format),
I counted 43 raw formats, each depending on the camera model.

One of the best image packages around is
[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php),
available as a package on Linux or as a download,
which supports a few RAW formats.
Use its commands of `magick` or `convert`.

However, the quality of the result would be very poor.
JPEG is processed image data while RAW is not.
Typically, RAW-files have 12-14-bit per pixel which means up to 16384 values.
JPEG can have only 256 luminance values per RGB channel.
This means that JPEG contains much less data than a corresponding RAW-file.
So there is no good way to convert a JPEG to RAW.

Comment: Absolutely. You shouldn't even attempt this. You will not get what you think you might get. See https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/73475/how-to-convert-jpeg-to-raw-in-photoshop-or-similar for some more reasons & possibilities for conversion if you're not convinced yet. There is no way to get back the information lost by saving your originals as jpg. Just remember to switch your camera to RAW before using it again.

Comment: @Steve Hello. If you talk about (scientfic) data, you have already compromised it. I agree with you that if the filter is well done you will not introduce further changes in the _single pixel_ values by converting them from jpg to RAW. But if not, you will do it... again. And if you just need to work on actual jpg images, you don't need any other layers of processing, you can start right from the images you have.

Comment: The bits-per-pixel numbers you've quoted are so misleading that it actually turns out JPEG has more bits per pixel than RAW (14 bits vs. 3x8 bits). Without explanation how RAW files work this part is very confusing.

Comment: @gronostaj: I meant 12-14 bits per pixel color for RAW, compared to 8 for JPEG. There are formats which use even more bits.

Comment: @harrymc That would be a bit better, but in RAWs [a single pixel may be composed from multiple subpixels for each channel](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/105272), so it's still not an accurate comparison.

Comment: "Very poor" is a matter of opinion. It will be pretty much exactly as "poor" as the JPEG, that is, all but indistinguishable to the layman's eye from the original camera's raw image!

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica, true, but if someone is generating a raw image, they're very unlikely to be using it for display to laypersons.

Comment: @Charles also true ;-). I meant that the typical jpeg is quite good, at least to good to characterize it as "very poor". It contains less information, of course, but it's not "bad".

Comment: Hi, sorry to say but Imagemagick programs and libraries only support **R**eading the Canon CRW and CR2 formats... (Check it with the [command line in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1620628/257269)) So you can `convert` from CRW to JPEG but not the other way. At least not in a simple way.

Answer (score 11):

#### Difficulties and opportunity of trying to convert JPEG into RAW format.

It is not always possible to convert a JPEG file to the original RAW file.
*Note: I speak about original or specific RAW format because it is not a standard: RAW formats are service formats, different one from another, used by the manufacturer to quickly save the contents of the CCD into the buffer and in case on the storage device.*

**Limits.** You might be able to turn it into a valid RAW format, but that doesn't mean the individual values stored in the new RAW file are the same as you might have if you saved the shot directly in RAW format.

**Opportunity.** It is not said that even if you can convert a JPEG image to RAW format and start from it for processing, the final result will be better than if you start directly from the JPEG you already have. In fact you will apply a filter (algorithm) that transforms one format into another and that can introduce further alterations.

**Difficulties.** Nonetheless, once you know [the specific RAW format](https://exiftool.org/canon_raw.html) you may find a way to *formally* `convert` the image into your RAW format. This will involve not trivial programming efforts, starting from the modeling of the inverse transformation and ending into coding in the preferred language the algorithm.

**Existing Programs.** The `convert` program from the [Imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) package under Linux (or other OSes) cannot convert any formats directly into the Canon RAW format, [it is only capable to read](https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) (**R**) them... So it can do the opposite of what the OP is searching for: to convert RAW to whatever.

```
convert -list format | grep Canon
      CR2  DNG       r--   Canon Digital Camera Raw Image Format
      CRW  DNG       r--   Canon Digital Camera Raw Image Format
```

But Imagemagick is even a **scripting**/programming language. Once that you have access to the single pixel values you may save them as you want... programming it. But you need to know the specifications of the desired format.

Moreover, since it is an open source program, you can see in the code the routines used to convert **from RAW** into whatever and see if you are able to *invert* them.

#### On the irreversibility of RAW to JPEG conversion.

This happens for many reasons. Among them:

- Some formats are lossy, JPEG is usually one of them. You save space at the cost of artifacts and a general modification of the original values for individual pixels.
- In the classic JPEG format there are only 8 bits for color (it means 256 shades). In a CCD sensor usually the couters are of 12 or 14 bits (that means 4096 and 16384 shades).
  If you think of your image as a histogram, you are going to average in a single bin (column) of the JPEG image, the values that are contained in 16 and 64 bins in the 12 and 14 bits counters respectively. How can you restore individual bin values from the average?
- Even if your JPEG is in the recent 12-14-16 bit format ([JPEG_XT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#JPEG_XT)), you are not aware of the algorithm used for this transformation inside the camera.
  (In simple terms, the sensor can have a non-linear efficiency curve. The manufacturer can take this into account by transforming the number from RAW format to a linear *shade* level in the JPEG, TIFF, ..., format.)
- The geometry of the CCD is different from the geometry of an image.
  Roughly speaking, in the images we have a pixel with 3 or 4 values relative to the exact same geometric square. All squares are adjacent.

  In the CCD instead we have geometrically separated sensors sensitive to different wavelengths, again speaking roughly for the R, G, B values. These sensors may or may not have the same surface, and certainly have a different efficiency which, among other things, changes according to the number of counts per second.

  How these RGB sensor sequences are aligned and spaced from each other depends on the design of the CCD. You can see some examples of [Color filter array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_filter_array) on internet.

  [image]
  <sup>Image from [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:An_RGGB_Bayer_Colour_Filter_on_a_1980%27s_vintage_Sony_PAL_Camcorder_CCD.png)</sup>

  [image]
  <sup>Image from [Ephotozine](https://www.ephotozine.com/article/digital-camera-image-sensor-technology-guide-16808)</sup>

  How the values of the counts of the red sensors translate, for example, into an image value of a pixel R, depends on their geometric position and on the algorithm chosen which may or may not also take into account the values of nearby sensors, either of those sensitive to the same as to other wavelengths.

  All of these things are hardly reversible.

Answer (score 3):

You can *not* do that.

You have to save as raw from the camera.

Once it is in JPEG format it would be like removing the cream from your coffee to try to make it a raw file.

Comment: That's simply not true. If the formats are known you can surely convert them. (It seems obvious to me but I'll state it explicitly to  avoid misunderstandings: You cannot recover information that is not present in the source format. But that is self-understood, I hope.) By the way, I do not understand your metaphor.

Comment: Pour cream in your coffee.  Stir.  Then try to separate the cream and the coffee.

Comment: Just so that I understand you better: You are using a metaphor of cream and coffee. What in the raw/jpeg problem corresponds to the cream, and what to the coffee?

Comment: the point is once you change to jpeg from raw you can not go back to raw as there were unfixable changes done to the image.

Comment: Obviously you cannot *reconstruct the original image;* but you surely can change *the format.* You still have not explained your metaphor.

Comment: I  explained the answer to the OP is correct.

Comment: You cant un-ring the gong.   You cant unkill a person. Some things have no reverse.

Comment: That is correct; but converting between file formats is not one of those things. To support your opinion, you should be more specific and concrete (e.g., refer to the data formats and the contents which prevent conversion) instead of providing metaphors.

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, there's no way to get the usual RAW format benefits when converting from JPG.

However, with Canon Powershot it's possible to use a custom firmware from  [CHDK](https://chdk.fandom.com/wiki/CHDK) project that makes it possible to take RAW images. Of course this won't help with existing images.